# web How to call and fetch data from api using worker?

Tags: javascript

I'm not understand how to call an api and fetch data from api using web worker in javascript.

```
fetch_worker.html

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>Web Worker API</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var Worker = new Worker('fetch_worker.js');
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>

fetch_worker.js
    const data = {
       userId: "A",
       setHeaders: {
          Token: 'fthsrrfl'
       }
    };
     fetch('api url...',{ method: 'POST' }, data).then (
        (response) => {
            console.log(response);
        },
        (reason) => {
           console.log(reason);
        }
     );
```

But I can't fetch data. How can I fetch data from api in web worker.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Az8mtkW.png — I copy/pasted your code, put a real URL in, and tested it. It worked fine. I can't reproduce the problem. Whatever it is, it isn't expressed in the code you shared.

Comment: what do you mean, you can't fetch? do you get an exception? some error message?

Comment: I call a local api to test it. But I get null value when I console response in JSON.stringify().

Comment: @Santu — "But I get null value when I console response in JSON.stringify()." — (a) That **isn't** what the code you shared with us does. (b) Why are you passing a fetch response object through JSON.stringify()?

Comment: In response I get these data:  body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "cors"
url: "url..."
__proto__: Response